# Subtract or add depending on method argument, eval alternate

Tags: ruby, eval, addition

Here is an example:

```
@current_day = 0
@current_time = 100

  def calc_day(amount, type = :add)
    calc_with = type == :add ? "+" : "-"

    @current_day = eval("#{@current_day} #{calc_with} (( #{@current_time} #{calc_with} #{amount}) / 1440)")
  end

  calc_day(:add, 2440)

  p @current_day
```

You could write the method above this way also:

```
def calc_day(amount, type = :add)
  if type == :add
    @current_day = @current_day + ((@current_time + amount) % 1440)
  else
    @current_day = @current_day - ((@current_time - amount) % 1440)
  end
end
```

My question is if there are ways not to use eval, but also dont have to write the whole expression twice with the + and - symbols be the only difference.

Comment: Time calculations are a solved problem in Ruby. You can, for example, do `Date.today + 2` etc. I'd even recommend using `active_support/core_ext` to be able to do things like `current_day + 1440.hours`. If this will ever be maintained by another Ruby dev, it will be more familiar than a hand-rolled method. If this happens to already be a Rails app, then you have no need to reinvent the wheel at all.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know this, but Im using Ruby as a scripting language for a game making tool. I wanted to script my own time system for the game engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send) to dynamically use `+` or `-` in your calculations:

```
def calc_day(amount, type = :add)
  calc_with = type == :add ? "+" : "-"

  @current_day = @current_day.send(calc_with, @current_time.send(calc_with, amount) % 1440)
end
```

Comment: Completely forgott about send. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can try sth like this:

```
def calc_day(amount, type = :add)
  method_names = {add: :+, subtract: :-}
  method = method_names[type] || raise 'Unknown calculation type'
  @current_day = @current_day.send(method,  (@current_time.send(method, amount) % 1440)
end
```

Comment: Thank you too, using a hash instead the ternary operator looks nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try multiplying with -1...

```
def calc_day(amount, type = :add)
  type_op = (type == :add) ? 1 : -1
  @current_day = @current_day + (type_op)*((@current_time + (type_op*amount)) % 1440)
end
```